# delta log (delta lake) - convert parquet to delta table issues

Tags: apache-spark, databricks, delta-lake

I'm using trying to convert parquet table to delta table in spark.
I'm able to convert the existing table into delta table using the below command,

```
import io.delta.tables._

val deltaTable = DeltaTable.convertToDelta(spark, "parquet.`path`")
```

This created delta log folder in the path along with

- lastcheckpoint
- 00000000000000000000.checkpoint.parquet
- 00000000000000000000.json files

inside it, we are good till now.

Next I try to insert data into the table, without any errors it would insert.
But I dont any new .json file or new checkpoint parquet file (after 10 inserts) in the delta log folder.

Instead I see all the inserts in a new parquet file.
It should be merged into one right? and every-time there should be a new json created after every inserts

What am I missing here? Any specific configuration?

- Spark - 3.2.1
- delta - delta-core_2.12-1.2.1

also using `--conf "spark.sql.extensions=io.delta.sql.DeltaSparkSessionExtension" --conf "spark.sql.catalog.spark_catalog=org.apache.spark.sql.delta.catalog.DeltaCatalog"`

Comment: You should add examples of how are writing and the files so we cab reproduce

Comment: To create a table,
spark.sql(f"""
CREATE TABLE customer
(Id integer, name string) 
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION '<PATH>'
""")
To convert parquet table into delta table,
import io.delta.tables._
val deltaTable = DeltaTable.convertToDelta(spark, "parquet.`path`")
To insert into a table,
spark.sql("insert into customer values(<>)")

Comment: When you use Delta, behind the scenes it creates a new Parquet file. Which parquet files to be used are all controlled by the contents of _delta_log folder.  Initially, Delta creates JSON files under _delta_log folder. After 10 updates, it creates a Parquet file inside delta_log.

Comment: Exactly my point ! But I’m not able to see any new json files under delta log folder. Only new parquet files are created. I’ve done more than 10 update to that table and nothing.